# Sed pattern to remove following line

Tags: linux, sed

I want to remove following stream

```
 warning: the use of `mktemp' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
```

I tried using following sed expressions:

```
sed \
-e '/mktemp\' is dangerous/D'
```

And

```
 sed \
    -e "/mktemp\' is dangerous/D"
```

But nothing works. What will be correct expression to remove that line from stream

Comment: The correct way to remove that line from the stream is to use `mkstemp` instead of `mktemp`.  Ignoring compiler warnings is a bad idea.  Writing scripts to suppress compiler warnings is a worse idea.

Comment: @WilliamPursell That code is in third party library. I don't want to change it's code.

Comment: If it's in a 3rd party library, why are you compiling it?  Compile it once, ignore the warning, and then just link to the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
sed -e "/mktemp' is dangerous/D"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$ cat /tmp/in.txt 
foo
bar
warning: the use of `mktemp' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
baz
$ sed -e "/mktemp'/d" < /tmp/in.txt
foo
bar
baz
```